# Downgrade my ruby and rails version.!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have downgraded my ruby-2.2.2 to ruby 1.9.3p551  and rails 4.2.4 to 3.2 version for my project now i am getting the dependency error of gemfile. How can I resolve these errors .? Is it possible to downgrade like this?

Comment: You also need to downgrade the dependencies to those compatible with rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: thanks for the time.  I have tried to change the dependencies. but when i resolve one dependency it give the error of other dependency it show the error for the previous dependency. Can you please provide my any link or any documentation to resolve this.

Comment: No document or link can help you resolve this, unless you tell us what your problem is...Just post the errors you got so that one can help you with those errors. In case if you are asking for a downgrade RoR checklist. It may differ from project to project...If you feel, there are some steps which are common to all projects during a downgrade. Please document (blog it) and help others...But, I don't think that would be the case...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change version of your gems, and then invoke

```
 bundle update
```

You have few options to specify how bundler should resolve dependencies. But when you didn't specify version of gem, then bundler choose latest compliant version.Eg

```
  gem 'sample_gem'
  gem 'sample_gem', '1.0.0'
  gem 'sample_gem',  '>=1.0'
  gem 'sample_gem',  '~>1.1'
```

So remove version from gem version you don't  care and then let bundler resolve dependencies.